# setState is delayed when using onChange to trigger function (react)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to coding and have just recently started using React.
I am selecting items from a drop-down menu using e.target.value. I am then setting the state of a variable with the value of the selected item.
However, the state value seems to be delayed i.e
I select item A and in the console logs I have selected item A but the state remains empty. Only once I select a new item e.g. item B, does the state update to reflect I selected item A.(screen shot below)

[screen shot of console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtJDc.jpg)

I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing

Please see the code below:

```
 class GetApi extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);


// Set initial state 
   this.state = {
   error: null,
   isLoaded:false,
   projects: [],
   title: ' ',
   description:'',
   url:'',
   id: '',
   // selectedOptionId: []
 };

// Binding this keyword
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 } 

 // handle onChange event of the dropdown
 handleChange = (e) => {
 console.log(`target value is ${e.target.value}`)

//update value of item id to be deleted
 const toDelete = e.target.value

  this.setState({ id: toDelete })
  console.log(`This.state.id = ${this.state.id}`)

 if (this.state.id === null){
 console.log('Error - Selected Option is Empty')  
 } else {
  console.log(`Selected ID is: ${this.state.id}`)
  }
 } 
 render(){
 return (
<Container>

{/* Delete Item */}
  <div className="delete">
   <select
    id='deleteSelect'
    name='projects'
    label= 'Projects'
    multiple={false}
  
    // assign onChange function
     onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
     {/* set list options */}
    {projects.map((item)=>(
    <option  key={item.id} 
    // let the value of the of dropdown be the id
    value = {item.id}
    >{item.id}:{item.title}
    </option>
    ))}
  </select>
  <Button
   onClick={(e) => this.delete(e)}>Delete</Button>
  </div>
  </Container>
   )
  }
 }
export default GetApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how `setState` works, it triggers a new render with the updated value but it doesn't update the current one.

Also I strongly encourage you to look at function components and hooks, classes have been kind of obsolete in React for many years.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the setState is working as it should - at least now I know the code is running the way it should. 
I will absolutely look into function components as opposed to classes - as a beginner it's hard to know what's relevant.